# Visual Basic - Command for new my.settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, settings

which the command to add a new My.Settings in visual basic without going into properties?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new file to your project and select the "Settings File" option:

[image]

Comment: @Gorfi - from there you can edit the contents of the file in VS, and access it from your code just like you normally would. What in particular were you trying to do?

Comment: i dont have this "Settings File" and i am using vb.net and you C# Items.

Comment: @Gorfi - it's still there (I just checked one of my VB projects). Look under the "General" category.

Comment: Who i can update my items so ? because i dont have this "Settings File"... i look under the "general" category too..